# Rails undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up an internal messaging system in my rails app and I'm having trouble getting the message to actually send to another user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # messages and conversations
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
  has_many :messages

class UserConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
  before_create :create_user_conversations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation

  delegate :subject, to: :conversation
  delegate :users, to: :conversation

  attr_accessor :to

  private
    def create_user_conversations
       to.each do |recip|
        recipient = User.find(recip)
        UserConversation.create(user_id: recip, conversation_id: 1)
       end
    end
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
  has_many :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_conversation
  belongs_to :user
```

And here is my user_conversation_controller:

```
class UserConversationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @conversation = @user.user_conversations.build
    @conversation.build_conversation.messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conversation = UserConversation.new(conversation_params)
    @conversation.user = current_user
    @conversation.conversation.messages.first.user = current_user
    if @conversation.save
      redirect_to user_conversation_path(current_user, @conversation)
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def conversation_params
      params.require(:user_conversation).permit(:to => [],
                                                conversation_attributes: [:subject, 
                                                messages_attributes: [:body]])
    end
```

The error comes in the create_user_conversations method in the UserConversation model. When I try to run

```
to.each do |recip|
```

I get an "undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass" error. However, the "to" array has a value in it, in this case the parameters looked like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "user_conversation"=>{"to"=>["2"],
 "conversation_attributes"=>{"subject"=>"Hey",
 "messages_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"body"=>"hey"}}}},
 "commit"=>"Create User conversation",
 "user_id"=>"1"}
```

Any ideas on why that array isn't getting passed in correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You define `to` as an `attr_accessor`, which will create get/set methods for an instance variable `@to`. You're using `to` as a local variable in your private method `create_user_conversations` though. This explains the `nil:NilClass` error.

Try changing the local variable to be an instance variable instead.

Comment: Can you post where exactly you're using the `create_user_conversations` method?

Comment: I'm using the create_user_conversations method in my UserConversation Model class only (shown above). I call it before a UserConversation is created with before_create.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by going ahead and adding a `recipients_id` column to my user_conversations table, then in my UserConversations controller I was able to do

```
def create
  @conversation = UserConversation.new(user_conversation_params)
  @conversation.user = current_user
  @conversation.conversation.messages.first.user_id = current_user.id
  if @conversation.save
    UserConversation.recipient_id = @conversation.recipient_id
    redirect_to user_conversation_path(current_user, @conversation)
    create_user_conversations
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

With the private method create_user_conversations also in my UserConversations controller:

```
def create_user_conversations
  UserConversation.recipient_id.each do |recip|
    recipient = User.find(recip)
    UserConversation.create(user: recipient, conversation: @conversation.conversation)
  end
end
```

I doubt this is the most elegant way to do this, but it at least gets the job done.